# Problems with entity framework and friends database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

just a simple question. I'm trying to create a simple friends database test application just to learn the Visual Studio 2010 entity framework and MySQL. The thing is, I don't know if this is right.

Here's a image of my current model:

[image]

The thing is, why are there two friend's navigation properties and two account navigation properties. I would have thought that maybe the friend entity is the only one that would have two account navigation properties so that I can reach the accounts for the two friends.

Here is my table layout:

- Account:

  1. idaccounts - Primary Key, Not Null
  2. nick - The users nickname
- Friends:

  1. idfriends - Primary Key, Not Null
  2. friend_one - The first account number
  3. friend_two - The second friend number
  4. status - Contains the status of the friendship (1. Pending, 2. Accepted, 3. Rejected)

Also, I created two foreign keys inside the friends table to the accounts table. One is named friend_one and it uses the friend_one column from the friend table to reference the accounts table. And the other one is named friend_two and it uses the friend_two column to reference the accounts table.

Is this the normal way to do it, or is there a better and more sane way?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's quite normal. If some account has more than one friend, you'll just add one more row to the **Friend** table.

Hovewer, I strongly recommnd you to read something about database normalization, if you still haven't :) Maybe starting from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Yes yes, I understand that, but I'm trying to link both columns in the Friends table to the Accounts table so that the relationship is clear, and also avoid duplication, I just thought that having bot the 1..* relations ship and two navigation properties inside the data model would lead to problems

Comment: why do you think there might be any problems with two navigation properties? I don't think that's gonna be a problem at all :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is.. it depends.  Normally, you don't repeat fields in one table, (i.e., FriendOne, FriendTwo, etc).  Because, lets say your a friendly guy (Mr. Wiggels sounds like a friendly name) and you have more than 2 friends.  Then what?

Below is how I would do it.  `Account` and `FriendAccount` are alias to the same Account table in the database.

[image: normalize account / friend schema]

However, if in your case your **sure** you will only ever have at most two friends, this would technically work.  But again, is probably bad design because it worn't scale.

Comment: Yes yes, that looks very good, but is that 3 different tables just to hold the accounts, friends and friend accounts? Cant friend point back to account's table and thus avoid having to create extra tables and inserting more rows

Comment: No, there are only two physical tables, #Account# and #Friend#.  #FriendAccount# is a alias for Account. What you have is a Many-to-many relationship between Accounts.  Now that I think about it, #FriendMapper# might be a less confusing name than #Friend# for the mapping table.

Comment: Oh, yes yes I see, now it makes more sense. Thanx!